# Excel: Compare and replace across sheets

Tags: excel

I have two spreadsheets. I need to compare and replace based on the other values.

So on sheet1 I need it to replace Column A with column C from Sheet2 if column A sheet1=Bsheet2.

Example

Column A Sheet1

Row1 = Steve

Column B Sheet2

Row4 = Steve

Column C Sheet2

Row4 = Bill

I need it to replace Column A Sheet1 Row1 "steve" with "Bill"

So if the two columns have a similar value it replaces it with the same row from column C on the second sheet.

Clear as mud.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).

> Use VLOOKUP when you need to find things in a table or a range by row. For example, look up a price of an automotive part by the part number, or find an employee name based on their employee ID.
>
> In its simplest form, the VLOOKUP function says:
>
> =VLOOKUP(What you want to look up, where you want to look for it, the column number in the range containing the value to return, return an Approximate or Exact match – indicated as 1/TRUE, or 0/FALSE).

Create a new column (`mapped`) and use `VLOOKUP` to populate it based on the value in Column A:

`=VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet2!$C$1:$D$10, 2, FALSE)`

Left to right:

`A1`: This is the search value (`steve` in your example).

`Sheet2!$B$1:$C$10`: This is the search range.  Adjust this as you see fit.  Make sure to keep the absolute `$` references in there as we do not want the search range to change as we move down the search values.

`2`: If a match is found in the first column of the search range, return the value in the second column.

`FALSE`: Require an exact match.  Change this to `TRUE` to return the closest match.  If this is `TRUE` then the data in `sheet2!B:B` should be sorted.

You can copy this down in column `mapped` to each row as needed.  Once populated you could:

- Hide the 'search value' column, leaving only `mapped`.
- Create another sheet, and inject the data from `mapped` using `=sheet1:B1`
- Copy the data out from `mapped`, then paste it over using `paste special / paste values`, which will discard the formulae and leave you with just the results.

Comment: Vlookup will help me return the rows that have the exact names but it won't replace the values with what is in Column C which is the time-consuming part. Right now I have to go row by row. If the results work then I can copy and paste the value from column C on sheet 2. I want some way for this process to automate. so find similar but then Replace with another value.

Comment: Do you want it to return the value if it is exactly the same, or a similar match?  If the latter, what does 'similar' mean?